# Why is heroku giving me errors when distributing Python app?

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to load via heroku CLI a python file with the requisites.txt file, but it gives me this error :

> remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement windows-curses==2.3.0 (from versions: none)
> remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for windows-curses==2.3.0

```
remote:          Downloading Werkzeug-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (224 kB)
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement windows-curses==2.3.0 (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for windows-curses==2.3.0
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 6c2f7309f6bb114265fc2426f30fe75abcd4044c
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 6c2f7309f6bb114265fc2426f30fe75abcd4044c
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to project.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/project.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/project.git'
```

i run these commands

```
1)heroku login
2)git init
3)git add .
4)git commit -m "test-1"
5)git push heroku master
```

Comment: Why do you install `windows-...` something on heroku which runs Linux, I hope?

Comment: @SUTerliakov i run pip freeze > requisites.txt

Comment: I'd also recommend cleaning out your virtual environment on your local dev environment (or copy it to a backup). Then try reinstalling from the requirements file. That can determine what version is going haywire.

Comment: @Dash2TheDot I cleaned up the environment a bit and managed to fix it, thanks